# How to convert HTML table with CSS media query to tree list?

Tags: html, css, printing, html-table, media-queries

In order to print an wide HTML table properly, I was wondering if we can convert the table without styling, etc. to a tree list or similar.

For printing reasons, this would solve a lot of problems with overflows and readability of large tables.

Comment: Take a look at this: https://css-tricks.com/responsive-data-tables/

Comment: Thanks, that's pretty legit!